# Magento 1: How to get pending order list outside Magento 1 framework?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I'm on a mission to list all pending/processing and completed order lists on my external application from a Magento 1 site.

I learnt by using following code I can get all orders from the site. But how do i get order listing based on order status?

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');

foreach ($orders as $order):
    echo $order->getRealOrderId().' - '.$order->getCreatedAtStoreDate().' - 
('.$order->formatPrice($order->getGrandTotal()).')<br>';
endforeach;
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello You can try this bit of code

```
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        //->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
        ;
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
        echo $order->getId() . ": '" . $order->getStatus() . "', " . $email .  "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Welcome Roshan ruzaik

Answer (score 2):

You can try this below code

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('complete','processing','pending_payment','canceled')));
```